# how can i export data out of salesforce to a oracle table automatically everyday?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I would like to export the data from salesforce to oracle database nightly . Is there a way to do this?

can't find a way to connect directly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct access to Salesforce database. You can only get in via SOAP/REST APIs. There's at least 1 connector for SQL Server (https://www.forceamp.com/) which pretends Salesforce is an ODBC-compatible linked database (or whatever is the right term), but it's a lie ;) It used to be a set of stored procedures, maybe they have something smarter now, maybe there's a similar offering for Oracle world...

I doubt you want to **implement REST callouts in PL/SQL** (although you might have it easier with sample Java connectors? Ask SF admin to export a WSDL file out of SF, "consume" it with Apache Axis, there's [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_list.htm))

You could use some **commandline** tools. If you have SF developer around they probably already use sfdx tool for code deployments. It can also [run queries, save results as csv](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211219/export-soql-cli-results-to-csv). Bit of effort and you could script a nightly sync.

You could use some **middleware**? BizTalk, Informatica, Azure Data Factory, MuleSoft have Salesforce plugins. Depends what you already use. Salesforce is also OData compatible, you'd have to read up about "Lightning Connect".

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation.